# Updating string in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux with react. I have a key in store whose value is a string.

This is what is get in `store.getState();`

```
{appBgColor: "#FFF"}
```

I am updating the store like this.

```
store.dispatch( changeAppBgColor("#FC0") );
```

**Reducer**

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_APP_BG:
    return { ...state, appBgColor: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Everything works fine, the appBgColor get changed whenever a new dispatch happens.

**Problem**

I have read that to change a key in redux store you should use concat, slice or join to make the state immutable. So I doubt I am doing it wrong. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes your code is correct..

Comment: You already are doing that, you're using the spread operator which makes a new object. So if you do something like `const x = {...state}`, then `x` and `state` are 2 distinct objects, and you can change `x` without mutating your state.

Comment: Thank you, wonder why the redux docs says we should use concat, slice or join to make the state immutable!!

Comment: @phantomCoder Next time, if you want you can ask such things to confirm to the Reactifux discord team.. It is like Slack. I am not sure if this kind of questions are good fit in SO model. If it does all good. Just wanted to let you know other sources where these kind of questions 100% fits.

Comment: @phantomCoder they say that because those methods don't mutate the array they act on (thus uphold immutability). You can use the spread operator for making duplicates of arrays too, but the spread operator isn't the only way to do so. `const x = state.array.slice()` and `const x = [...state.array]` both make separate copies of an array that you can then mutate without affecting the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use-case of updating the field `appBgColor` within your state, your reducer implementation is **correct**.

Note that when you return `{ ...state, appBgColor: action.payload}`, you are not mutating the state, but in fact, creating a copy of the existing state, applying the change and returning it. This makes sure that the state is **immutable**, ie it is not directly modified.

You would only need to use functions like slice, concat etc when you are updating nested items within your state. For eg, when you need to remove an element from an array within your state, you would need to use `slice` as shown below.

```
const index = state.findIndex(a => a.id === action.id)
return [
    ...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)
]
```

Comment: @phantomCoder does this answer your query? Let me know if it doesn't.